# Javascript hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I trying to get the following script run on the client-side but currently no rows are being highlighted for the table id = `tbDetails`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tbDetails tbody tr").hover(

function () {
    $(this).css({
        background: 'yellow'
    });
},

function () {
    $(this).css("background", "");
}
);
</script>
```

I have debugged the script using the browser tool and the script was throwing the following error - `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.  I resolved this error by adding the following jquery library to my html but above the script is still not working on my client side.

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

here is full view of my html and javascript:
[JSFiddle HTML example](https://jsfiddle.net/miss/9t5fvgsh/)

Any advice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729383/2025923 might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first add jQuery to your fiddle. Also remove `background-color: #ffffff;` from 
`table.gridtable td` class.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/9t5fvgsh/6/) is your updated fiddle, that you posted in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your feed, I was unaware the css class `table.gridtable td` background property was causing the conflict.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `background-color:#ffffff`

```
table.gridtable td
{
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`$(this).css("background", "");` should be `$(this).css({"background": ""});` and `$(this).css({background: 'yellow'});` should be `$(this).css({"background": 'yellow'});`

```
$("#tbDetails tbody tr").hover( function () {
        $(this).css({ 'background': 'yellow'});
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css({"background": ""});
    });
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9t5fvgsh/7/)**

Comment: This is just another syntax. It is not an answer to the OP's problem. The reason why your demo works and the OP's does ot is given in @Sourabh-'s answer.

Comment: @  ImreNagy give me some `demo link ` with this syntax $(this).css({ background`,` 'yellow'}); I am sure you would nt

Comment: You added an error no one ever mentioned. It is not the OP's syntax.

Comment: @ ImreNagy but it is the standard syntax

Comment: What I mean is this line from your example: `$(this).css({ background, 'yellow'});`. Nobody said that this syntax is correct. Not even the OP. So adding this error in your code is not an argument for your answer to be correct.